# Equal power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $f_1(z) :=
\sum
\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z -a)^n$ and
$f_2(z) :=
 \sum
\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_n(z -a)^n$ be two power series with
radius of convergence $R > 0$.
Assume that there exists a sequence $(z_k) $ in $B(a;R)$
such that i) $\lim_k z_k = a$ and ii) $f_1(z_k) = f_2(z_k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$. Show that $a_n = b_n$ for
all $n$.

I can't think of a way to solve this, only thought I had was to assume $a_i \neq b_i$ for some $i$ and reach a contradiction, but I can't proceed much.

Comment: It's Identity theorem!

Comment: @MyGlasses It seems, but I can't understand the proof on Wikipedia

Comment: Proof of Identity theorem?

Comment: Start with proving that $a_0 = b_0$. Then proceed by setting up an induction argument

Comment: Let $A=\{z\in B(a,R): \text{in on neighborhood of} a, f_1(z)=f_2(z)\}$

Comment: and $B=\{z\in B(a,R): \text{in on neighborhood of} a, f_1(z)\neq f_2(z)\}$

Comment: and make a contradiction with connectedness of $B(a,R)$.

Comment: The hypotheses are not sufficient to prove that the two power series are the same.  In particular if $z_k\equiv a $ for all but finitely many $k$, it is possible for the power series to have different coefficients in some entries.  I suspect you omitted an essential assumption about the sequence $z_k$.

Comment: OP: Since you accepted he answer below, you might want to explain what $A$ and $B$ are in it since at present their definition makes no sense.

Comment: And 17 minutes, naturally.

Comment: @ab123 please remove mark from my answer. I want to delete it!

Comment: @MyGlasses but why?

Comment: It has error!.. My goal was you find the solution and it is enough!

Comment: @MyGlasses Ok, now you can delete

Comment: But why was it wrong?

Comment: It was incomplete and you can find the answer in complex books. Thank you about un-mark!